# Is it true that the center of a finitely generated nilpotent group is finitely generated?

Tags: finitely-generated, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ be a finitely generated nilpotent group.
Let $Z = Z(G)$ be the center of the group $G$.
Is $Z$ finitely generated?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is true. A finitely generated nilpotent group is Noetherian, i.e. any subgroup is finitely generated. In particular the center is finitely generated.

To see why a finitely generated nilpotent group is Noetherian, first show that the property of being Noetherian is closed under group extensions. Next, any term in the lower central series is finitely generated. The factors of this series are finitely generated abelian groups. These are Noetherian by the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: Can you introduce a strong reference that contains this contents?

Comment: What I wrote is really all you need. An even more direct proof will be to say that a finitely generated nilpotent group is polycyclic (i.e. has a composition series with cyclic quotients) + the fact that Noetherianity is preserved under extensions.

Comment: You can start by trying to prove that any subgroup of a finitely generated abelian group is finitely genereated :-)